# modification of private file (using mmap) with child process can't be seen from the parent

Tags: c, linux, fork, mmap, child-process

I have a file with following string, "Hello ". First I'm making private file of that file (using mmap). Then I'm adding string "World" to the end of the private file (so it would have now "Hello World"), but this modification can't be seen from the parent even though I used mmap before fork.

I have no idea where I have made something wrong.. :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



int main(){
    int status = 0;
    int txt_len = 6;
    int str_size = 5;
    char str[5] = "World";

    int fd = open("hello_string.txt", O_RDONLY);
    lseek(fd, 12, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, "", 1);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *map;
    map = mmap(NULL, 11, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    int n;  
    int c;
    for(n = 0; n < txt_len; n++){
        read(fd, &c, 1);
        map[n] = c;
    }   


    //Create child process
    pid_t childPID;
    childPID = fork();

    if(childPID >= 0){
        //Child
        if(childPID == 0){      
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < str_size; i++){
                c = str[i];
                map[txt_len + i] = c;          
            }       
        }
        //Parent
        else{
            //Wait for the child        
            waitpid(childPID, &status, WUNTRACED); 

            int n;
            for(n = 0; n < txt_len + str_size; n++){
                printf("%c", map[n]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }   

    }
    //Fork failed
    else{
        printf("Fork failed, exiting!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why is the file opened as readonly, yet you're trying to write to it? Also, a bug, in there, if the file does not exist... you should be taking care of that.

Comment: If I don't want to modificate the original file, shouldn't it be read only? When creating private map, it is for reading and writing. And yes there should be if statement to check if file exist but I'll add it later. It's not the problem in this case. And I also have to add munmap and close for original file :)

Comment: No, am talking about the `lseek` / `write` / `lseek`, you were reading beyond the end of the `fd`, attempting to write empty string... which seems redundant anyway. Have you debugged it, stepped into the code with it?

Comment: ouch, thanks, bad mistake. I changed it to -> O_RDWR but won't still work. I read somewhere that lseek / write / -phase is needed to use mmap correctly, but it was false information? :D

Comment: childPID should be just greater than 0, not greater than or equal to 0. Parent process will always have PID > 0. Child's PID should be 0. Did you actually debug this code?

Comment: Private mappings are exactly that - private. After the `fork` the child process does indeed inherit the parent's mappings. But it does not mean they can see each others changes. Private mappings are Copy-on-write and thus are independent from the point of the `fork`.

Comment: suggest reading/understanding the man pages for `open()` and `mmap()`.   Note: always check the returned value from these two functions to assure the operation was successful.   Note: fork() gives the child a copy of the data, not the actual data

Comment: these lines: `  for(n = 0; n < txt_len; n++){
        read(fd, &c, 1);
        map[n] = c;
    } ` do nothing as they are reading from the file and writing to the file. (remember map[] is the file, now imaged in memory

Comment: this line: `char str[5] = "World";` does not allow enough room for the literal "World", which, including the trailing NUL byte is 6 bytes long.

Comment: on linux (and probably other systems) read() and write() functions have their prototypes included by: `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: regarding this line: `map = mmap(NULL, 11, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);`  the value: `MAP_FILE` only exists for compatibility, and generally should not be used.

Comment: after calling `mmap()` the returned value should be compared with `MAP_FAILED` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Since the posted code is going to append to the file, strongly suggest the open be `read/write` rather than `read only`

Comment: the file will contain a END OF FILE sequence, which will push its' size beyond 11 bytes

Comment: this detail should be noted: "  Use of a mapped region can result in these signals:

       SIGSEGV
              Attempted write into a region mapped as read-only.

       SIGBUS Attempted access to a portion of the buffer that does not corre‐
              spond to the file (for example, beyond  the  end  of  the  file,
              including  the  case  where  another  process  has truncated the
              file).
"

Comment: when calling `lseek()`, always check the returned value with `(off_t) -1' to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code is missing `#include <sys/types.h>` which is used in the `waitpid()` function as the third parameter

Comment: the returned value from calling function: `waitpid()` should be checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: So, what I'm trying to do is impossible? I have to use SHARED file?